# bash script that works both on Ubuntu and MacOsX

Tags: linux, bash, ubuntu, vim

I've created an install.sh files for my ubuntu machine. This file aims to start configuration  of my dotfiles in an ubuntu machine. But I've also a MacOsX machine.

> ```
> #!/bin/bash
> clear
> SCRIPT=$(readlink -f $0)
> SCRIPTPATH=`dirname $SCRIPT`
> cd $SCRIPTPATH && git submodule update -i
> rm -rf ~/.vim
> ln -s $SCRIPTPATH/.vim ~/.vim
> rm ~/.vimrc
> ln -s $SCRIPTPATH/.vimrc ~/.vimrc
> rm ~/.bashrc
> ln -s $SCRIPTPATH/.bashrc ~/.bashrc
> ```

This is what I get if I run same script in MacOsX:

> ```
> readlink: illegal option -- f
> usage: readlink [-n] [file ...]
> usage: dirname path
> fatal: Not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git
> ```

How can I convert my "install.sh", thus it can run both on MacOsX and Ubuntu?

Answer (score 0):

Just use the first argument for the scriptname:

```
SCRIPT="$0"
```

`$0` is always available and always contains the full script name. You only need `readlink` if you are executing the script from a link in order to return the actual target name of the script.